# From integral to hypergeometric series

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, trigonometric-integrals

Hello everyone and thanks for your time.
I would like a suggestion on how to evaluate these integrals using the hypergeometric series (rewrite them in the form of hypergeometric series)

$$\int_0^x \frac{\sin (x)}{\sqrt{a-\sin(x)}}\, dx$$    where $$0<a<1.$$ (Sorry if I put the extreme of integration coincides with the variable of integration, but I put it to show that it too is variable).

$$\int_0^x \frac{\cos (x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x)-b}}\, dx$$   where $$0<b<1$$
and 
$$\int_0^x \frac{\sin (x)}{c+d\sqrt{a-\sin(x)}+e\sqrt{\cos(x)-b}}\, dx$$

$$\int_0^x \frac{\cos (x)}{c+d\sqrt{a-\sin(x)}+e\sqrt{\cos(x)-b}}\, dx$$ where $c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c,d,e>0.$

Of course I know that derive the expression in hypergeometric series of each integral would lose much time,so if someone can suggest me how to do, or show me the process I would be very grateful.
Unfortunately, my whole knowledge on i ipergeometrici are still insufficient and too new to be able to be applied easily,and that's why I can not pass by the integral Readily to the generalized hypergeometric series.
Thank you again for your interest.

Comment: If you don't have access to "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by Gradshreyn and Ryzhik; I can copy 2.57 (2) and (6).  The solution involves two functions I am not familiar with.

Comment: I put up a generalized answer and then deleted it.  I think I have a more instructive solution to the problem illustrating some properties of the Generalized hypergeometric functions and their relationship with binomial sums.  I will try to put it up this afternoon.